# TF207005 Issue while linking Test Result to Change Request in TFS2015.3

Tags: tfs, workitem

When I try to link a Test result to Change Request in TFS2015.3, I get below error:

"TF207005: The current work item already contains links to the following work items: XXXXX".

Please help to resolve this error.

Regards,

Chirag D S

Comment: Are you trying to link a Test result to a Change Request work item under CMMI process template?

Comment: Yes it is a CMMI Process..

Answer (score 0):

To link a test result to a work item, you **must open the test result** and associate the work item with the test result.

It' not able to  associate multiple Test Results with a single Change Request work item.

Double check if there already been a test result.

Comment: No, I do not have any other Test Results linked to the Workitem. It is  only for 1 Workitem -  Test Result combination, I am not able to link

Comment: @Chirag Did this kind of issue occur for each change request? Have you tried to link the test result to any other change request work item. Or you could try to link another test result to that particular change request. This will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Other CRs are fine. Only this particular pair is not working. I am able to lilnk this CR with other Test Results and vice versa.